# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x221756b90) to 'NSString' (0x221753d80)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I made MetodChannel in my flutter app. But i have crash..
This is code on Flutter side

```
void startNotifications() async {
  try {
    var methodChannel = MethodChannel('com.test/notificationsChannel');
    await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('startNotification');
  } catch (_) {}
}
```

And this is code od Swift side

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let notificationChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.test/notificationsChannel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
  
  notificationChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      switch(call.method){
      case "startNotification":
          break;
      default:
          return
      }
  })
```

Error crash:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x221756b90) to 'NSString' (0x221753d80).
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001fe71c2f4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`:
->  0x1fe71c2f4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1fe71c310               ; <+36>
    0x1fe71c2f8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1fe71c2fc <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1fe71c300 <+20>: bl     0x1fe717cd4               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Time4BUS) stopped.
```